# Copy all files from one source to another Gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am trying to copy all .css files within subfolders to another folder with gulp

```
gulp.task('copyCss', function () {
    gulp.src('/bower_components/*.{css}')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/content/css'));
});
```

But this does not work, because in bower_components i have a lot of subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the nested directory. Try using `gulp-flatten`:

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
    gulp.task('copyCss', function () {
        gulp.src('/bower_components/**/*.css')
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/content/css'));
    });
```

Comment: I only need css file not entire folder structure

Comment: Did you try this...? It will only copy file unless you specify your `base` in source.. So it should only copy files

Comment: No yit copy folder structure also